# Pygame, I can't make the quit command work

Tags: object, int, pygame, typeerror

```
def closeWindow():
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT():
            isRunning = False
```

when ever I call this I just get a TypeError: 'int' object is not callable. Anyone got any tips for me??

Answer (score 1):

Change `pygame.QUIT()` to `pygame.QUIT`. `pygame.QUIT` is actually just an integer (`12`) and it doesn't make sense to call it like a function: `12()`.